# It is possible to order alphabetically the series in Oxyplot chart legend?

Tags: wpf, charts, legend, series, oxyplot

I would like to order the `legend` of my Oxyplot chart in an `alphabetical order`. Is that possible within `Oxyplot`?

Here is my current plot: [Plot with legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cASiQ.png)

I would like to order the `legend` of my `chart`. I would not order the way in which I plot the data first because it would imply too many conditions and I want to keep the plotting as general as possible. I know this would be an option, but I would rather not go with this method.

Please let me know if it is possible to `order alphabetically` only the legend items in `Oxyplot`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot modify the order of the legend directly, but you can sort the series inside the model, so you will see the **legend alphabetically sorted**:

There you have 2 methods to do the sorting:

**Option 1, Simple Bubble Sorting:**

```
Series temp;
int length = plotModel.Series.Count;
for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j < length; j++)
    {
        if (string.Compare(plotModel.Series[i].Title, plotModel.Series[j].Title) > 0) //true if second string goes before first string in alphabetical order
        {
            temp = plotModel.Series[i];
            plotModel.Series[i] = plotModel.Series[j];
            plotModel.Series[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

**Option 2, Auxiliary List:**

```
List<Series> sortedList = new List<Series>(plotModel.Series);
sortedList.Sort((x, y) => string.Compare(x.Title, y.Title));

plotModel.Series.Clear();
foreach(Series s in sortedList)
    plotModel.Series.Add(s);
```